# webdriver.support.select - Select doesn't interact with the element

Tags: selenium, python

I have the following select:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
<label class="ph_label pointer city">
<span class="l citylbl">City</span>
<select class="cities custom-dropdown" data-validation-error-msg="You  must select a city" required="" name="city" disabled="disabled" data-validation="required">
<option value="">City</option>
<option value="Shanghai">Shanghai</option>
<option value="Beijing">Beijing</option>
<ul class="cities custom-dropdown" data-target-selector="select.cities" style="width: 293px;">
</label>
</div>
```

I'm trying:

```
mySelect = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name("city"))
mySelect.select_by_value("Shanghai")
```

When I see the test run, selenium goes through this element as if everything was OK, but in fact the city was not selected. Am I missing something?

Comment: Strange indeed. If your option value and visible text are always the same, try `select_by_visible_text()` - IIRC it is faster. Is it possible that city is not found, select raises exception, and you silence it somewhere?

Comment: I've tried putting `select_by_visible_text()` but nothing interact with this element.

Comment: You might try selecting by index of the dropdown if it is consistent

Comment: Did you tried to step through your code with a debugger? Put line `#import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` before `mySelect =`. BTW according to PEP8, it should be `my_select` :-)

Comment: What UI framework are the developer using? The select is hidden, you need to interact with UI not the hidden select.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `<select>` html:  disabled="disabled"

This disables that particular select box.  Selenium can only interact with the web page as if it were a user, so it cannot set the `<select>` directly.

You need to figure out what actually sets the value of the `<select>`, then use Selenium to drive that.

Comment: This is the answers, most UI frameworks work like this. We are using Semantic UI and this framework also hides the select, you need to interact with the HTML/Javascript dropdown replacing the browser select tag.

Answer (score 0):

If You cannot alter the html directly You can insert some script code to re-enable the select field:

```
driver.execute_script("$('select.cities').removeAttr('disabled')")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is using AngularJS and select2. If yes, there are 2 ways
1. Click on the dropdown, then search the value you need

> *mySelect.Click();*
>
> *selectSearchBox.Sendkey(searchBox,"Shanghai");*

2. Using JS to enable/display the dropdown as @Joern Boegeholz commen

> *driver.execute_script("$('select.cities').removeAttr('disabled')")*